# Vbulletin add reply to posts

Tags: post, button, vbulletin, reply

I'm trying to add a reply button inside the post, for example if I leave a post on a thread another user can click a reply button inside the post.

here is an image that explains it better - http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=2a013d0

Thanks for any help I'm a newbie to vbulletin

Comment: seems this was a silly question, you get this option in the default toolbar. I just moved it into the post and it did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems this was a silly question, you get this option in the default toolbar. I just moved it into the post and it did the trick